# Npm script for building react app working locally but not in pipeline

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-devops

I have the following package.json for my React project

```
{
  "name": "webforms-react-sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample projects for hosting React apps in a WebForms application.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build-dev": "npx webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build-prod": "npx webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "author": "Dimitris Vardalis",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.6.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to run the `build-dev` script. When trying locally I can make that script to work as is expected so build is made. But when going to the build pipeline is returning me this:

```
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: webpack@5.75.0
CLI for webpack must be installed.

> webforms-react-sample@1.0.0 build-dev
  webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)

We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D webpack-cli".
> npx webpack --config webpack.dev.js

Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): 
##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
```

I'm using Azure Devops and a windows machine agent (always using the latest version) for running the pipeline. And yes I'm installing npm packages before the step when trying to run that script. I don't have any npm cache step to avoid Azure caching old files and not updating on releases (this happened to me on other pipelines).

Current pipeline is this (see pictures)

[pipeline steps part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqly7.png)

[Pipeline steps part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHQR8.png)

I have already tried uninstalling the packages and reinstalling them, same results and been breaking my head for a while and still the same results.

Comment: You have webpack in your devDependencies is there any reason you still use npx instead of just using the local webpack?

Comment: Sorry for delay. I was taking a break after work. Yes idk why azure fails to me when not using npx. Error that throws me is that webpack is not recognized a as an internal or external command

Comment: how exactly is your ADO pipeline lined up? please update your question to include screenshot if it's classic UI based pipeline or share YAML code

Comment: @Sibtain added the steps for the pipeline setup, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made it work by changing npm install step on React to npm install --force.